# Clicking Reanalyze Now gets me a 403 error

Tags: security, health-analyzer

I am in the farm administrator's group. Every time I click on the "Reanalyze Now" I get redirected to a "403 FORBIDDEN" page.

I am on SharePoint 2013 Enterprise.

Comment: For which health rule are you getting this?

Comment: Pretty much all.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try running the analyser jobs using Power Shell. Check this out: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/01/force-run-sharepoint-health-analyzer-jobs-ondemand.html

Comment: I am a SharePoint Farm administrator, but don't have privileges to the server itself.

Comment: That could be potential reason for 403 error, don't you think?

Comment: Forgot we set up Kerberos on the server. Got the admin to add me. Thanks.